# Cortar palabra al contar 21 caracteres

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente codigo de producto donde necesito poder contar 21 caracteres y poder contar la palabra con el metodo `split`.

0207FLOREB04408002400**PUTNNN**

mi split queria asi

```
var codigo = "0207FLOREB04408002400PUTNNN";
var split_code = /*RECORTA AL ENCONTRAR 21 CARACTERES*/
console.log(split code[0]); /*0207FLOREB04408002400*/
console.log(split code[1]); /*PUTNNN*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas buscando `substring()`.  Ejemplo:

```js
var codigo = "0207FLOREB04408002400PUTNNN";
var split_code0 = codigo.substring(0,21);
var split_code1 = codigo.substring(21,27);
console.log(split_code0);
console.log(split_code1);
```

Comment: No convendría contar el total de caracteres y donde pusiste el 27 poner esa variable? Digo, por si le llegan mas de 27 le quedarían caracteres afuera de split_code1

Comment: No se si convendria o no.  Depende de lo que OP necesite.

Answer (score 0):

saludos podrias hacer algo como esto:

```js
var codigo = "0207FLOREB04408002400PUTNNN";
var resultado = codigo.split(/(.{21})/).filter(O=>O)
data = [];
for(i=0; i<resultado.length; i++){
 if(resultado[i].length == 21 ){
  var element = {}
  element.codigo = resultado[i];
  data.push(element);
 }
}
console.log(data);
```

Si te fijas mediante una expresión regular separa cada 21 dígitos, acto seguido mediante un ciclo for valido que sean 21 y los asigno en un array de esta manera tendría los deseados.

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar alguna funcionalidad de ES6 como `filter`:

1. Primero haces el `split` por cadena vacía para devolver un `array` con todas las letras de la frase
2. Aplicar `filter` para devolver aquellos elementos cuyo índice en el `array` sea menor de 21.
3. Unes los elementos con un `join('')` para devolver un `string`.

```js
var codigo = "0207FLOREB04408002400PUTNNN";
var split_code = 21;
console.log(codigo.split('').filter((e,idx) => idx < split_code).join(''));
```